# how to call these static/specific pages template collectively on index.php by using loop through get template part?

Tags: wordpress

I have created static page templates in Wordpress which named page-slider. PHP, page-images. PHP, etc. kindly help me how to call these pages collectively on index.php by using a loop through get the template part?

```
 <?php
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'pages',
);

query_posts($arg);
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'page-', 'the_slug()' . '.php' );

endwhile;``

?>
```

I have tried like above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the conditions for each page while template call.

```
<?php
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'pages',
);

 query_posts($arg);
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if(is_page('slider')){
        get_template_part( 'page', 'slider' );
    }
    if(is_page('images')){
        get_template_part( 'page', 'images' );
    }

endwhile;

?>
```

You can use the same format in index.php file

Comment: can you check which file is calling? index.php or page.php?

Comment: If page.php is calling for the pages then you need to add the logic inside that file without using the while loop and wp_query : like the following if(is_page('slider')){
        get_template_part( 'page', 'slider' );
    }
    if(is_page('images')){
        get_template_part( 'page', 'images' );
    }

Comment: sir i try this on page.php but still its not working.

Comment: i tells you again what i want to do..i have created static page templates from different section of one page html template, now i want to call these templates(page-slider.php,page-image.php) on index.php or page.php by loop unless using get_template_part function again & again for each file,for example i want just like this <?php
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'pages',
    'the_slug' => 'page-slider.php'

);

query_posts($arg);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'page-', 'the_slug()' . '.php' );

endwhile;

?>

Comment: kindly sir help me out

Comment: 20 reputations require i am new here